# Unity - Arm goes backwards instead of back down when blending animations?

Tags: unity, blender

I'm putting together an animation tree which is layered, and it seems to get between two animation states it blends the arm backwards over the top of the head rather than back down. Is there anyway to set constraints in your rig or sort this any other way? Either through blender or unity so that it blends the proper way?

All help is welcomed! Cheers,

edit - have updated with snips to the blend trees. I'm not blending back to tee pose, rather I have the attack animations masked on another layer. I've got 3 animations that it plays between back to an empty state when not "attacking". One of those animations, when it blends between the falling and attacking, it swings the arm backwards rather than forwards.

[image: Base Layer]

[image: Attack Layer]

Comment: It might help if you edit this question to show the animation blending setup that leads to this unwanted transition.

Comment: It sounds like it may be blending to the T-Pose with he arm up next to the character (Probably what the blend animation is exiting too)

Comment: Good advice! Have updated with some snips of the arrangement